# how to show “Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" in product listing page

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, product

I am using Magento 1.9. I want to show "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" in list.phtml page. For example I have set minimum quantity "6" in Product attribute then it should show "6" in front end.
I am trying to write this code but it is throwing an error. Maybe I am writing a wrong code.

```
 <?php 
$productQuantity = Mage::getModel("cataloginvetory/stock_item")->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
echo $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty(); ?>
```

I am getting following error

Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByProduct() on a non-object in **/**/list.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some logic

```
<?php                 
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
                 echo $stockItem->getMinSaleQty() && $stockItem->getMinSaleQty() > 0 ? $stockItem->getMinSaleQty() * 1 : null;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getModel("cataloginvetory/stock_item")` is not returning an object. Use `var_dump()` to find out what Mage's static function is returning.

```
echo var_dump(Mage::getModel("cataloginvetory/stock_item"));
```

I presume it will return with NULL or false. If that is the case something is going wrong in `getModel()` (probably incorrect parameters)

Comment: Yes it is returning "bool(false)". So what should i do in that case?

Comment: check with the Magento documentation to see what it means when `getModel()` returns false. From what I have read I assume there is a problem with the module you are passing as a parameter. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588748/magegetmodel-is-returning-false may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes that I see right off the bat.

First, "cataloginvetory/stock_item" is a typo. It should be "cataloginventory/stock_item."

Second, loadByProduct takes a product - not a productId.

It should look like:

```
<?php 
$productQuantity = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")->loadByProduct($_product);
echo $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty(); ?>
```

I wasn't able to test the getMinSaleQty() function because I don't have that enabled on my site.